# How do I calculate the bending of filtration in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have 2 variables:

- Image which contain original image.
- FilteredImage which is filtered image.

Both are RGB images. I know how to calculate the bending for 2-D images

```
Image = unread('C:\Users\klass\Pictures\man.jpeg');
NoiseImage = minimise(Image,'gaussian');
ImageFiltered = NoiseImage;
for c = 1 : 3
    ImageFiltered (:, :, c) = medfilt2(NoiseImage(:, :, c) [3, 3]
end
Bending = norm(im2double(Image - FilteredImage))/norm(im2double(FilteredImage)) * 100;
```

When I try to use this formula to my figures I get this error:

> Error using norm
> Input must be 2-D.

Comment: What is `Filtered(Image)`? Is that supposed to be `FilteredImage`?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Your statement also misses two closing parentheses. Please post a [mre], it will make it easier to understand what is actually going on. In MATLAB, `norm` with a 2D input computes a matrix norm, it is unlikely that you want to apply that to an image. What do you want to compute the norm of? Each RGB value?

Answer (score 0):

I tried pass 3-D images to `norm()` function. The work around is convert each image to 2-D by `rgb2gray()`function.
Therefore I evacuate banding with formula:

```
Bending = norm(im2double(rgb2gray(Image) - rgb2gray(FilteredImage)) / norm(im2double(rgb2gray(Image))) * 100
```